# How to stop Fabric from running

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-fabric

I've went through documentation: http://support.crashlytics.com
It doesn't seem to question the purpose of the app, so I will ask here :)

I have Fabric integrated in my app. As per installation process, I've installed Fabric app on the Mac I am working on.

Now, from time to time, I have Fabric app that keeps opening, which I personally find very annoying. It's too much for a 3rd party service (even for a great one as Fabric Analytics).

In the build steps in Xcode I've found a script, but doesn't seem that it does the thing:

```
#!/bin/sh

#  run
#
#  Copyright (c) 2015 Crashlytics. All rights reserved.

#  Figure out where we're being called from
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

#  Quote path in case of spaces or special chars
DIR="\"${DIR}"

PATH_SEP="/"
VALIDATE_COMMAND="uploadDSYM\" $@ validate run-script"
UPLOAD_COMMAND="uploadDSYM\" $@ run-script"

#  Ensure params are as expected, run in sync mode to validate
eval $DIR$PATH_SEP$VALIDATE_COMMAND
return_code=$?

if [[ $return_code != 0 ]]; then
  exit $return_code
fi

#  Verification passed, upload dSYM in background to prevent Xcode from waiting
#  Note: Validation is performed again before upload.
#  Output can still be found in Console.app
eval $DIR$PATH_SEP$UPLOAD_COMMAND > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

So what is Fabric App is really for? Can it be excluded from the workflow? Can I actually erase it and continue the management through Pods? What's the trick behind it?

Answer (score 3):

Because this question is still relevant, to prevent Fabric from launching, you got two options:

**1. Stop it after uploading your project’s DSYM file.**

Open up the run script: Pods/Fabric/run and change:

```
eval $DIR$PATH_SEP$UPLOAD_COMMAND > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To:

```
eval $DIR$PATH_SEP$UPLOAD_COMMAND;killall Fabric > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**2. Stop it and only upload DSYM when archiving builds for release:**

Check the “Run script only when installing” option under Build Phases:

[image: Run script only when installing]